# On a convergence theorem for stochastic processes that have bounded sum of expected differences.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $ \{ Z_t \}_{ t \in \mathbb{N} }$ be a real valued positive stochastic process defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}  )$ and adapted to a filtration $ \{ \mathcal{F}_t \}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$. Let
$$
\sum_{t \ge 1} E[ \boldsymbol{1}_{F_t}( Z_{t+1} - Z_t   )  ]  < \infty
$$
where $\boldsymbol{1}_{F_t}$ represents the indicator function on the set $$F_t := \{ \omega \in \Omega  | E[ Z_{t+1}(\omega) - Z_t(\omega) |   \mathcal{F}_t ] > 0 \}$$  Then is it true that
$$
Z_t \xrightarrow[]{\text{a.s.}} Z_{\infty} \ge 0
$$
where $Z_{\infty}$ is an integrable random variable.

Comment: Is it only for me or is the latex rendering weirdly? I can't seem to change it by editing.

Comment: $F_t := \{ \omega \in \Omega  : E[ Z_{t+1}(\omega) - Z_t(\omega) |   \mathcal{F}_t ] > 0 \}=\{ \omega \in \Omega  : E[ Z_{t+1}(\omega)  |   \mathcal{F}_t ]- Z_t(\omega) > 0 \}$

 We can see that $F_t$ is $\mathcal F_t$ measurable since $E[ Z_{t+1}(\omega)  |   \mathcal{F}_t ]$ and $ Z_t(\omega)$ are $\mathcal F_t$ measurable.


Then by Tower property 

$$ E[ 1_{F_t}( Z_{t+1} - Z_t   )  ] =E[E[1_{F_t}( Z_{t+1} - Z_t   )  |\mathcal F_t]]=E[1_{F_t}E[( Z_{t+1} - Z_t   )  |\mathcal F_t]]$$

Comment: Since $F_t$ is the set on which the conditional expectation is positive we see that 
$E[1_{F_t}E[( Z_{t+1} - Z_t   )  |\mathcal F_t]]\geq E[E[( Z_{t+1} - Z_t   )  |\mathcal F_t]]=E[( Z_{t+1} - Z_t   )].$


Then 


$\sum_{t \ge 1} E[( Z_{t+1} - Z_t   )]\leq \sum_{t \ge 1} E[ 1_{F_t}( Z_{t+1} - Z_t   )  ]  < \infty$

And then we can see that we necessarily have $\lim_{t\to\infty} E[ Z_{t+1} - Z_t  ]=0$


So the sequence is Cauchy in $L^1$, so it must converge in $L^1$, but I am not sure about the a.s. convergence. (there will a.s. convergence of a subsequence though)

Comment: I don't publish it as an answer since it does not address your question.

Comment: @RScrlli  Very interesting though, thanks!